# Mavericks Login Screen Mirrored on 2nd Monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display

I recently had to erase and restore my mac as it developed a terrible hard drive failure, and ever since I've had odd behaviour (already posted one other question today). For some reason the Login screen is mirrored on both my monitors and annoyingly this changes the resolution and aspect ratio shown on the MacBook, I really don't like it, and it's never done this before. It also creates a strange animation as the screen logs in which I fins even more annoying. Before the second monitor would show the background of the login screen but certainly would not effect the resolution of the main screen or be mirrored. What's going on there?

Thanks,
Mike

Two screenshots, one of the displays and a profile error which I can't help but feel is also a side effect of the issue I had.[image][image]

Comment: Could we see the Screen drivers settings in your ColorSync app located in your Utility folder

Comment: @Buscar웃 Sure, which screen shot would you want specifically, I'll attach one now, but if you need more, just say.

Comment: Is it just the login window that appears on both screens? Once you log in do you see two different sets of icons/windows/etc, or the same one mirrored?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan Everything is perfect once logged in, the displays are extended correctly as far as I can tell.

Comment: Have you attempted a reset of the PRAM/NVRAM?  Hold command+option+P+R as you power on the Mac, releasing all of the keys after you hear it chime three times.

Comment: Alternately, have you pressed command+F1 (shortcut to switch between mirroring and extended desktop) while at the login screen?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Sorry for the delay, pictures are now up.

Comment: @MrRabbit while I definitely haven't pressed that, pressing it on the Login screen fixed the issue, had no idea that was the shortcut. Feel like a numpty for not thinking of something like that. Problem solved

Comment: @Mackey18 - No worries, for whatever reason that's not a well publicized shortcut.  If I didn't work in an office environment where everyone has a second monitor then I wouldn't have thought of it.  I'll make than an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is the shortcut for switching between mirrored (same thing on both displays) and extended desktop (each display is independent) modes.

Pressing that while at the login screen should sort your problem.